# Flutter web view windows desktop support

Tags: flutter, webview, desktop

i am trying to add WebView into my flutter windows application, but WebView_flutter and flutter plugging don't support windows, i am trying to use url_launcher library but it open the url in PC browser, and i am aiming to hide my url from the users.

Any one have any idea about how to embed a video into my Desktop Windows application ?

Answer (score 1):

If video is all you need, try using VLC with this lib https://pub.dev/packages/dart_vlc. They have Windows and Linux support. Then you can load your video from the network inside your app.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to **Enable Web**, to do this follow these Steps:

- `flutter channel dev` OR `flutter channel master`
- `flutter config — enable-web`

After Web is Enabled, revert the channel to the Stable Channel

- `flutter channel stable`